# Error: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss/colors'

Tags: npm, tailwind-css, npm-install

Running `npm run dev` or `npm run watch` gives this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@uppy/core/dist/style.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].oneOf[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].oneOf[1].use[2]!./node_modules/@uppy/core/dist/style.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss/colors'
```

Heres the full error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@uppy/core/dist/style.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].oneOf[1].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].oneOf[1].use[2]!./node_modules/@uppy/core/dist/style.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss/colors'
Require stack:
- C:\Projects\myapp\vendor\wireui\wireui\tailwind.config.js
- C:\Projects\myapp\resources\views\themes\tailwind\tailwind.config.js
- C:\Projects\myapp\resources\views\themes\tailwind\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\lib\setupTrackingContext.js
- C:\Projects\myapp\resources\views\themes\tailwind\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\index.js
- C:\Projects\myapp\resources\views\themes\tailwind\node_modules\laravel-mix-tailwind\index.js
- C:\Projects\myapp\resources\views\themes\tailwind\webpack.mix.js
- C:\Projects\myapp\resources\views\themes\tailwind\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js
- C:\Projects\myapp\resources\views\themes\tailwind\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js
- C:\Projects\myapp\resources\views\themes\tailwind\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js
- C:\Projects\myapp\resources\views\themes\tailwind\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
- C:\Projects\myapp\resources\views\themes\tailwind\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\myapp\vendor\wireui\wireui\tailwind.config.js:1:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
```

Comment: could you be more specific in your question and add the tailwind.config.js